# How to "denormalize" custom class and keep sync?

Tags: c#, class, denormalization

I need to "denormalize" class to have another dictionary in connections class whose key is the connection ID and value(s) is/are the names. I need to keep those two dictionaries in sync.

Class

```
public class ConnectionMapping<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>> _connections =
        new Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>>();

    public void Remove(T key, string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_connections)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;

            if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                return;
            }

            lock (connections)
            {
                connections.Remove(connectionId);

                if (connections.Count == 0)
                    _connections.Remove(key);
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class myHub : Hub
{
    private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections = 
       new ConnectionMapping<string>();
    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        string name = userName;  
        _connections.Remove(name, Context.ConnectionId);
       //_connections.Remove(Context.ConnectionId); <-- I need
    }
}
```

How to "denormalize" ? I need to use `_connections.Remove(connectionId)`

Comment: Do you know what the word "denormalize" means in this context?

Comment: I guess is to create another dictionary in connections class to keep sync. Am I wrong?

Comment: "In computing, denormalization is the process of attempting to optimize the read performance of a database by adding redundant data or by grouping data"[1]

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization

Comment: You need to show how the database (dictionary in your case) was being accessed before and how its different now so that you are reducing the amount of 'joining' that needs to happen, thus increasing read time.  You should clarify your question.

Comment: I did update, see plz. Is it clear now?

Comment: No I still don't understand how your data is structured.